# Updating SVG with js dynamically and embedding it to other site

Tags: javascript, svg, embedding

I am trying to use javascript inside svg file to update some text dynamically and then embedding the svg to another page by calling it with URL.
So it should be like this, in another site I write,

`<img src="mysite.com/shape.svg?t=TheText" height="100" width="100" />`

and it should show up like this:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYZWW.jpg)
but when in the target site the svg shows up like this
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtFtt.jpg)

If I go to the link(mysite.com/shape.svg?t=TheText) directly then it first shows up without the text and some milliseconds later the text appears. I assume js makes the changes after the svg is first rendered and the other site only gets the first empty shape without the text that embeds there.
inside svg I am using this line to change the text of svg

`document.getElementById("a5").textContent="The Text"`

Now, my question is, is there any way to make the svg appears as intended without any delay or without first loading the empty shape? so that the other site gets the correct svg for embedding as I wanted?
I am trying to not use server-side things for this little thing, that's why I am using js inside svg.

Comment: Load the SVG file as text; replace what you need to replace; then inject the SVG: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Comment: Could you share the contents of your SVG?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I am not facing problem in embedding the svg in the other site. the problem is, in my site, where I am hosting the svg file with js, it it loading the empty svg first and then changing the text on side. The other site is only getting the first emty svg, not the final text change.

Comment: @JohnPavek  sure, here it is
`<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="100" height="100" fill="#FF6E40"/>
<text fill="white" xml:space="preserve" style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="24" letter-spacing="0em"><tspan id="a5" x="4" y="62.2031">The Text</tspan></text>
<script>
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const text = urlParams.get('t');
    document.getElementById("a5").textContent=text;
</script>
</svg> `

Comment: an IMG will never run ``<script>`` because that would allow XSS attacks: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/212894/is-there-a-way-to-execute-xss-in-an-html-img-tag-with-svg

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman perhaps you got it wrong. Its not running anything, its just passing the t parameter with URL inside img src. and JS runs in svg. Its kind of like the way all the little badges work in the github.